# assembly programming error: syntax error : in directive; syntax error in structure field

Tags: assembly, x86-16

i have some portion of assembly program "msdos.asm". when i try to compile it then it is showing the error explaining: "syntax error : in directive" for all the fields of the structure.

```
FCBLOCK STRUC
        DB      12 DUP (?)              ;Drive code and name
line(80)   EXTENT  DW      
line(81)   RECSIZ  DW             ;Size of record (user settable)
line(82)   FILSIZ  DW             ;Size of file in bytes
line(83)   DRVBP   DW             ;BP for SEARCH FIRST and SEARCH NEXT
line(84)   FDATE          DW             ;Date of last writing
line(85)   FTIME   DW             ;Time of last writing
line(86)   DEVID   DB             ;Device ID number, bits 0-5
                                ;bit 7=0 for file, bit 7=1 for I/O device
                                ;If file, bit 6=0 if dirty
                                ;If I/O device, bit 6=0 if EOF (input)
line(90)   FIRCLUS DW             ;First cluster of file
line(91)   LSTCLUS DW             ;Last cluster accessed
line(92)   CLUSPOS DW             ;Position of last cluster accessed
                   DB             ;Forces NR to offset 32
FCBLOCK ENDS
```

MSDOS.ASM(80) : syntax error : in directive

showing above mentioned error for all the fields of the structure FCBLOCK.
   for example EXTENT,RECSIZ,FILSIZ.......CLUSPOS.

It is showing "syntax error : in directive" error for all the fields of FCBLOCK structure.
when i initialize the fields with some value for example:
"EXTENT DW 1212H"
then the error disappears.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Yes, syntactically you need an initializer, which can just be a `?` :)

Answer (score 1):

`DW`, `DB`, etc. are used to declare *initialized* data fields. The initialization values are not optional. It sounds like you want `RESW`, `RESB`, etc. instead.

Comment: `resb` and friends are NASM syntax, which doesn't seem to be used by the question.